# SharePoint site to display all report, published with in "My workspace" in Power BI

Tags: power-automate, powerbi

I want my SharePoint site to display all reports (titles & URLs), published within "My workspace" in Power BI. It should be automated so that in the future if new reports are added or removed in "My workspace", it automatically updates the SharePoint list.

Is this possible by using Power Automate or any other tool?